# Gatling make one scenario run once in a chain of scenarios

Tags: scala, gatling

I have a scenario where I have to perform certain steps. But I do not want the users to log in multiple times. So i chained the scenarios, but the login still happens multiple times. Is there any way to restrict part of the chain to run only once?

```
class CreateUserSimulation extends Simulation {
val login = Login.getExec()
val userCreate = UserCreate.getExec("basic")
val userJourney = scenario("User Journey")
    .exec(login)
    .exec(userCreate)

setUp(      
    userJourney.inject(constantConcurrentUsers(10) during (2 seconds))
).protocols(Params.httpProtocol)
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't want the users to log in multiple times"? Gatling will run the scenario for different users (10 x second over 2 seconds). That means that you should see 20 logins when this scenario is run.

Comment: I would like to use the same credentials ( cookies etc) for creating the UserCreate exec

Comment: What you're proposing is the situation where a user logs in and then is making lots of requests concurrently. Is this really a good reflection of what happens in your system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a variable that will say whether or not you are in the system

```
val userJourney = scenario("User Journey")
.exec(_.set(isLogin, "0"))
.doIf(session => session("isLogin").as[String].equals("0")) {
  exec("login")
    .exec(_.set("isLogin", "1"))
}
.exec(userCreate)
```