# I want to use the one api's result into another api in karate-gatling. Both api's are being simulated in gatling

Tags: performance, karate

I have a GET api which returns some data, I need to use that data in POST api on which I am supposed to simulate load testing for continuously over a period of time.

I am able to corelate those api, but when I do load testing it is simulated on both the apis. I want to do load testing only on post api. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to define 2 Gatling scenarios and do this. So please read the documentation.

And in the latest version of Karate you should be able to pass data from 2 different feature files in 2 different Gatling scenarios. Please see the docs here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-gatling#chaining

Something like this:

```
val chained = scenario("chained")
   .exec(first)
   .exec(karateSet("extraKey", s => "extraValue"))
   .exec(second)
```

You can find a complete example here: [`TestSimulation.scala`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/v1.1.0/examples/profiling-test/src/test/java/perf/TestSimulation.scala)

So now you should be able to figure out how to use the Gatling syntax so that the first Gatling scenario is executed only once. This answer is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60116256/143475

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply, Peter. But what I am doing in my case is I am calling both get and post call in a scenario in a feature file. when I call that scenario in gatling's scala class, simulation is being happened on both the apis. but I do want simulation only on post api.

Comment: @Nasruddin I give up. you can help by doing some research and posting here what you find. all the best